# Python Increment a number in a function called with multiprocessing.pool.map()

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to increment a number sequentially in a function that is called by multiprocessing.pool.map(). When I run the following code I get the number incremented the same number of times as their are pools for each number.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import decimal
import random

lists = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','i', 'j', 'k']
def thefunction(listi):
    global number
    number += 1
    time.sleep(decimal.Decimal(random.random()))
    print time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), number, listi

number = 0
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(thefunction, lists)
print number
```

The results print out like this

```
01:01:28 1 b
01:01:28 2 e
01:01:28 1 a
01:01:28 1 c
01:01:28 1 d
01:01:28 2 h
01:01:29 2 i
01:01:29 2 g
01:01:29 3 f
01:01:29 3 j
01:01:29 3 k
0
```

How can I increment the number correctly?

(time.sleep(decimal.Decimal(random.random())) was only added to stop the script printing to the same line)

Comment: Have you tried `lock`ing while you're accessing the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the example is not working is that several instances of the counter are being created and incremented separately.

You need to create a shared counter and lock that are initialized appropriately for each process that is started:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, Lock
import decimal
import random

number = Value('i', 0)
lock = Lock()
lists = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','i', 'j', 'k']

def thefunction(listi):
    time.sleep(decimal.Decimal(random.random()))
    with lock:
        number.value += 1
        print time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), number.value, listi

def initializer(*args):
    global number, lock
    number, lock = args

pool = Pool(4, initializer, (number, lock))
pool.map(thefunction, lists)
print number.value
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the whole thing in a `multiprocessing.Lock`?  with this, the "parallelizable" part (`time.sleep()`) always runs sequentially.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy. Oops, yes - silly copy & paste error. Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. More complicated than I'd hoped lol but just what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome, what I was looking for the past hour!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a [`multiprocessing.Value`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) for the shared state.

Or rather, that will do what you *ask* but it might not be what you really *want*;  Shared state in a parallel context is usually a sign of a design flaw.  One thing you could do instead is to have each process keep track of how many items it has processed, and return *that* count to the parent;  the parent can then total the number of jobs completed by each to sort out how much work has been done up to this point.

What is the reason you're trying to count across process boundaries?

Comment: I had a feeling my luck was about to run out and this part was going to be to complicated. I don't know how to interact with the running processes or pass vaules as you suggest but will take a look at multiprocessing.value. Thanks. This code is a simplified version of a script where the function takes between 10-30 minutes to complete, running through a list of about 40 items. I'm just trying to gauge how far through the list the script is so I can guess how long its going to take to complete.